# Is there any way to see file history after squashed commits in git

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose i have `five commits` and i edited one file called `sample.txt`

```
Commit A   - updated bla 1
Commit B   - updated bla 2
Commit C   - updated bla 3
Commit D   - updated bla 4
Commit E   - updated bla 5
```

Now when i click on history of that file in bitbucket then i can clearly see how the files was chnaged and easily see the diffs visually between each diffs

But when someone squash the commits then the only thing i can see is

```
Commit F   - squashed commit of the following
```

Now i can't see the history and diff between each commit

Is there any way to see the enitre histroy of file with individual commits without squashed ocmmit

Comment: No, that's the whole point of a squashed commit! If you want to keep the history, don't squash it.

Comment: @GregHewgill other coders are doing it for purpose. they dont want other to know history.  but i an new coder i dont have any say, is there any way to counter that thing. i mean i create some local branches etc